# How to make AzerothCore and TrinityCore realms to share the same authserver

Tags: trinitycore, azerothcore

Is it possible to run one [AzerothCore](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk) *worldserver* and one [TrinityCore](https://github.com/TrinityCore/TrinityCore) *worldserver* and have them to **share the same *authserver***?

If yes, which authserver should I select?

Also, what about permissions? Since for [commands](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/data/sql/base/db_world/command.sql) permissions, AzerothCore is using the MaNGOS-like [account_access](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/data/sql/base/db_auth/account_access.sql) while TrinityCore is using [RBAC](https://trinitycore.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/tc/pages/2130095/RBAC+Role+based+Access+Control) ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

You can use the authserver of Trinitycore (Need to use auth database of Trinitycore too).

Add missing tables & fields of tables from azerothcore auth database to your trinitycore auth database. (For find missing run worldserver of azerothcore to see what fields of tables are required to import on error messages. like ip2location tables.)

For permissions, TC uses RBAC, So you must manage RBAC with your TC worldserver.

For AC, you must manage the commands table.

If you want to make a gm account on TrinityCore realm. use worldserver command `account set gmlevel`.

for AC realm you must use this command on AC worldserver.